# User Input error handling with python and SQL

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, input, error-handling, output

I am trying to create an input function (maybe better as a loop) where the user inputs a name of an object that comes out of a SQL dataframe.  I have my code working now where if the user inputs a correct name of an object, the code returns the correct information, but there is no error handling for an incorrect string.

```
   def elementcall(input_ele):
        cur.execute(f"SELECT Name FROM iElements WHERE Name={input_ele}")
        # row = cur.fetchall()
        cols = cur.fetchall()
        while cols:
            cols = cur.fetchall()
            
    elementinput = input('Enter a System Name:')
    elementcall(elementinput)
```

I input Plane, which is in the dataframe and the code properly returns the correlating information from the SQL database when I just have the input line.

The function above kicks back an error involving how the code is reading the SQL data, stating that the column Plane does not exist.

I have also tried a loop to solve the error handling, but this method kicks back the error message no matter what I type.

```
while True:
     elementinput = input('Enter a System Name:')
     if elementinput in iElements['Name']:
          break
     else:
          return print("You typed something wrong!")
```

Any suggestions?  The SQL dataframe is a has a column named Index, ID and Name and I would like for the code to look up the information by name.
%%% UPDATE

```
e = iElements['Name']
    e_list = e.tolist()
    
    # for elem in e_list:
    elem = input('Enter a System Name:')
    if elem in e_list:
        # elementinput = input('Enter a System Name:')
        return elem
    else:
        print("You typed something wrong!")
```

How about this last section?  Same goal, ask for an input and if it is in the list then the code continues to work with the input, but if the input is not in the list then the error returns.  Do I need my entire code in the loop or can the inputed string leave the loop and work in the rest of my code?

Comment: elementCall does not return anything

Comment: I have deleted that since I posted this, I realized I left it in here after I posted the question.